# How do I pass parameters to the form builder?

Tags: forms, 8

I have the following routes in module_name.routing.yml.

```
module_name.usergroup_delete:
  path: 'module_name/usergroup/delete/{arg1}'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\module_name\Form\DeleteUserGroup'
    _title: 'Delete User group'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access admin menus'
```

This is the code in module_name/src/Form/DeleteUserGroup.php.

```
namespace Drupal\module_name\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\ConfigFormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class DeleteUserGroup extends ConfigFormBase {

  public function getFormId() {
    return 'delete_user_group';
  }
/**
 * General form for switching all nodes from one user to another.
 */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state,$product_code) {
  $form['_product'] = array(
        '#type' => 'value',
        '#value' => $product_code,);
//get the user group and username to display the confirmation message 
$result = db_query('select field_p_group_name_value from {content_type_usergroup} ctu'       
        . ' where vid=%d',$product_code);      
    while ($row = $result->fetchObject()) {
      $user_group = $row->field_p_group_name_value;
    }

return confirm_form($form,t('Are you sure you want to delete "' .$user_group. '" User Group?'),
        isset($_GET['destination']) ? $_GET['destination'] : "function_name",t('This action cannot be undone.'),t('Delete'),t('Cancel'));

  }
/**
 * #submit callback for node_adoption_transfer_form().
 */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form_values = $form_state->getValues();
  //if ($form_state['values']['confirm']) {
    $param = $form_state->getValue('_product');
    drupal_set_message(t('Group ' .$param.' will get deleted.'));               
    db_query('DELETE FROM {content_type_usergroup} WHERE vid = %d', $param);
    //delete the users of the usergroup too
    db_query('DELETE FROM {usergroup_user_map} WHERE group_id=%d', $param);
    drupal_set_message(t('usergroup has been deleted.'));
    drupal_goto('function_name');
  }

  protected function getEditableConfigNames() {
    return "delete_user_group";
  }

}
```

I am getting the following error:

> DeleteUserGroup::buildForm() must be compatible with
>   Drupal\Core\Form\FormInterface::buildForm(array $form,
>   Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state)

Why?

Comment: Can anyone explain how this equates when using the WebForm module? I have no module specifically for the form I have built using the module, so what would the point '_form' to within the routing.yml file ?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The parameter has to have the same name in routing.yml and build method. And when using parameters in forms you have to set a null value in the parameter list:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $arg1 = NULL) {
```

Comment: Ah yes! The additional parameters always have to be `NULL` to be compatible with `Drupal\Core\Form\FormInterface::buildForm`.

Comment: @leymannx I would be even concrete that additional parameters should be optional (nullable) with defaults like `NULL`, 'some_string', '2' and so on.
See for example `core/modules/comment/src/Form/CommentAdminOverview.php`

BTW: it is true for any method that follows interface where you want to add extra parameters.

Comment: Is this and second highest rated answer still valid (D9/D10)? It seems to me you explicitly need to state the parameter under defaults in the routing.yml and it's been put to '' instead of NULL (in form class too). Like can be seen: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/6a19b3a01ffcabeee34e0499456cbd86a0dae96f/core/modules/ban/ban.routing.yml and https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/6a19b3a01ffcabeee34e0499456cbd86a0dae96f/core/modules/ban/src/Form/BanAdmin.php#L61

Comment: Ah okay, seems to depend on form class from which you derive, ConfigFormBase seems to require the param in the defaults in routing.yml, while just FormBase does not. That said, not sure why the BanAdmin Route uses this, seems not necessary.

Answer (score 15):

First create a routing.yml file

```
admin_notes.form:
  path: '/example_module/form/{arg}'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\example_module\Form\ExampleForm'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

Then create a `.php` file under folder structure `/src/Form/ExampleForm.php`. Then build a form

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $arg = NULL) {
  $form['example_note'] = [
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#title' => $this->t('Block contents'),
    '#description' => $this->t('This text will appear in the example block.'),
    '#default_value' => $arg,
  ];
  $form['actions'] = ['#type' => 'actions'];
  $form['actions']['delete'] = [
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => $this->t('Delete'),
  ];
  return $form;
}
```

Comment: default `arg:` should be passed in route definition.

Answer (score 6):

This is not asked in the question. Maybe it could also help, I had to pass a parameter to a form that was not loaded by a route. The form is integrated into a template loaded by a controller.

In `custom_module.routing.yml`:

```
path: '/lorem/{arg}'
defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\LoremController::testLorem'
```

In the controller, the form is called and the parameter `$arg` is passed to the form builder.

```
public function testLorem($arg) {
     $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\my_module\Form\testForm', $arg);
     $build = [
         '#theme' => 'custom_theme',
         '#form' => $form,
         '#arg' => $arg,
     ];

     return $build;
}
```

And in the form :

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface   $form_state, $arg = null) {
}
```

Comment: I came here looking for exactly this. Thank you!