# Is there a way to populate a form with dynamic values?

Tags: forms, 9

I might be missing the point of the form api, but I was wondering if I can somehow create a form and initialize it with dynamic values?

Here is what I'm trying to do:

**my_module.module**

```php
function my_module_preprocess_user(&$vars) {

     $sponsorshipsEligibleForPackagereceiving = SponsorshipUtils::getPackageSendEligableSponsorships((int) $vars['user']->get('uid')->getString());


     // this will call ConfirmDeliveryForm::buildForm straight - how can I pass sponsorshipsEligibleForPackagereceiving to it?
     $formRenderElements = Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm(ConfirmDeliveryForm::class, $state);

     $vars['handle_block'] = $formRenderElements;
}
```

Is there a way to initialise the ConfirmDeliveryForm with $sponsorshipsEligibleForPackagereceiving before the buildForm is used?

The form itself would then allow the user to modify stuff via the ajax callbacks.

Alternatively I could probably just initialize $sponsorshipsEligibleForPackagereceiving inside of ConfirmDeliveryForm::buildForm function with the currently logged in user?

Thx a lot for your help!

Comment: You are already passing a variable with a different name as form argument. You should be able to receive it in buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $extra = NULL)

Comment: @4uk4 - you're right! It exactly works like this :D. Thx a lot - If you would like to post this as answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable passed in formBuilder::getForm()

```
$form = Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm(ConfirmDeliveryForm::class, $extra);
```

is available in buildForm() as extra argument:

```
buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $extra = NULL)
```

You need to set a default value for the extra argument, see [How do I pass parameters to the form builder?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199926/how-do-i-pass-parameters-to-the-form-builder)